# Javascript file totally not loading in WP theme when setting all 5 parameters in wp_enqueue_script()

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I tried to find my answer in existing questions but I could get my answer right. I have a problem with loading .js file in my wordpress theme.
There are two problem . One appears when I write code like this.

```
wp_enqueue_script('myJsFile',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/myscript.js','NULL','microtime()',true);
```

In this case , the file totally disappears. no any function Or Code works. even in 'view source' file, it is not showing anywhere.

Buuut , when I remove the 3rd and 4th and 5th parameter , then in 'view source' page it starts appearing but with catche . mean the file  do not update and the old codes that i have even removed from the file are rendering.

Comment: That `microtime()` function shouldn't be without quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the third and fourth parameter, it should be use without quotes. The working code is:

```
wp_enqueue_script('myJsFile', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/myscript.js', NULL, microtime(), true);
```